# Setting up and accessing Flink Queryable State (NullPointerException)

Tags: streaming, apache-flink

I am using Flink `v1.4.0` and I have set up two distinct jobs. The first is a pipeline that consumes data from a Kafka Topic and stores them into a Queryable State (QS). Data are keyed by date. The second submits a query to the QS job and processes the returned data.

Both jobs were working fine with Flink `v.1.3.2`. But with the new update, everything has broken. Here is part of the code for the first job:

```java
private void runPipeline() throws Exception {
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = configurationEnvironment();

    QueryableStateStream<String, DataBucket> dataByDate = env.addSource(sourceDataFromKafka())
        .map(NewDataClass::new)
        .keyBy(data.date)
        .asQueryableState("QSName", reduceIntoSingleDataBucket());
}
```

and here is the code on client side:

```java
QueryableStateClient client = new QueryableStateClient("localhost", 6123);

// the state descriptor of the state to be fetched.
ValueStateDescriptor<DataBucket> descriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor<>(
    "QSName",
    TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<DataBucket>() {}));

jobId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
String key = "2017-01-06";

CompletableFuture<ValueState<DataBucket> resultFuture = client.getKvState(
    jobId, 
    "QSName", 
    key, 
    BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO, 
    descriptor);

try {

    ValueState<DataBucket>  valueState = resultFuture.get();
    DataBucket bucket = valueState.value();          
    System.out.println(bucket.getLabel());

} catch (IOException | InterruptionException | ExecutionException e) {
    throw new RunTimeException("Unable to query bucket key: " + key , e);
}
```

I have followed the instructions as per the following link:
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/state/queryable_state.html

making sure to enable the queryable state on my Flink cluster by including the `flink-queryable-state-runtime_2.11-1.4.0.jar` from the `opt/` folder of your Flink distribution to the `lib/` folder and checked it runs in the task manager.

I keep getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.GenericTypeInfo.createSerializer(GenericTypeInfo.java:84)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.state.StateDescriptor.initializeSerializerUnlessSet(StateDescriptor.java:253)
    at org.apache.flink.queryablestate.client.QueryableStateClient.getKvState(QueryableStateClient.java:210)
    at org.apache.flink.queryablestate.client.QueryableStateClient.getKvState(QueryableStateClient.java:174)
    at com.company.dept.query.QuerySubmitter.main(QuerySubmitter.java:37)
```

Any idea of what is happening? I think that my requests don't reach the QS at all ... Really don't know if and how I should change anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as it turned out, it was 2 things that were causing this error. The first was the use of the wrong constructor for creating a `descriptor` on the client side. Rather than using the one that only takes as input a name for the QS and a TypeHint, I had to use another one where a `keySerialiser` along with a default value are provided as per below:

```java
ValueStateDescriptor<DataBucket> descriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor<>(
    "QSName",
    TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<DataBucket>() {}).createSerializer(new ExecutionConfig()),
    DataBucket.emptyBucket());    // or anything that can be used as a default value
```

The second was relevant to the host and port values. The port was different from `v1.3.2` now set to 9069 and the localhost was also different in my case. You can verify both by checking the logs of any task manager for the line: 
`Started the Queryable State Proxy Server @ ...`.

Finally, in case you are here because you are looking to allow port-range for queryable state client proxy, I suggest you follow the respective issue (FLINK-7788) here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-7788.